# Take a photo opencv + python 3.3

Tags: python, opencv

I want to take a photo when the user press 's'. This is my code and I don't find why it's wrong.

```
import cv
import sys

win = 'Camera'
cv.NamedWindow(win)
cap = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)


while cv.WaitKey(1) != 27:
img = cv.QueryFrame(cap)

cv.ShowImage(win, img)
if cv.WaitKey(10) == 115:
cv.SaveImage('test1.jpg', img)
```

The mistake said:

File "dos.py", line 14
    cv.SaveImage('test1.jpg', img)
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: So, what happens when you run it? Any errors?

Comment: For your information, OpenCV supports python 2.6 and 2.7 version only, not 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code since [Python uses the indentation of the code](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) to figure out where a block of code begins and ends.

You can also specify the filename with double quotes:

```
if cv.WaitKey(10) == 115:
    cv.SaveImage("test1.jpg", img)
```

Comment: File "dos.py", line 14
    cv.SaveImage('test1.jpg', img)
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block